# How to get collection from shipping_tablerate table rate shipping module from magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

How do I get the collection from shipping_tablerate table rate shipping module from Magento 2.3?

I need to check customer postal code eligibility to table rate shipping module

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a plugin to override this method **collectCarrierRates** located in **/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php** to check if postcode customer input that meet your requirements and then do your logic. Not sure what do you really want here, so I apply a general solution to you and this can apply to other cases as well. You can also switch to before and around plugin depends on your need.

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Magento\Shipping\Model;

class Shipping
{

    public function afterCollectRates(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject,
        $result,
        $request
    ) {
        $allproducts = $request->getAllItems();
        $postcode = $request->getDestPostcode();
        if($postcode == 'your value here') {
            'your logic here'
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```